# Change sheet tab color depending on CountA function result

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have a document with several sheets. Every workbook represents the projects of the company and the number of hours that a employee worked on them.

There are probably 25 tabs and i need to color the tab, when the cells are empty or not empty.

I am using the following macro, which WORKS. but depending of the sheet that i am watching, it will change EVERY TAB COLOR, based on the sheet that i am watching. It doesnt modify the color independently. Any idea why this happens?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorTabs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim CountaRange As Range
    
    Set CountaRange = Range("B7:H26")
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(CountaRange) = 0 Then
           ws.Tab.Color = vbRed
        Else
           ws.Tab.Color = vbBlue
           
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I am expecting to color every tab independently. Not all tabs at once.

Comment: Your `Set CountaRange = Range("B7:H26")` is meant for each looped sheet ? or just the active sheet ? If it's meant for each looped sheet then `Set CountaRange = ws.Range("B7:H26")` inside the loop. So if the looped sheet Range("B7:H26") countA result is zero - then the looped sheet tab color is red, if not zero then the looped sheet tab color is blue. But if it's meant for just the active sheet, it will make the tab color all the same depends on the active sheet countA result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your range inside your loop with the `ws.` prefix. Currently your range is set based on your `ActiveSheet` and doesn't change for each tab.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorTabs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim CountaRange As Range
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set CountaRange = ws.Range("B7:H26")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(CountaRange) = 0 Then
           ws.Tab.Color = vbRed
        Else
           ws.Tab.Color = vbBlue
           
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```